# How to create a multi-row equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I'm having trouble creating an equation, where the first part spans 2 rows. I can do it using a table. This code outputs the style I want it in, but then latex assumes it's a table instead of an equation.

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Multi-column and multi-row table}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \multirow{2}{*}{$S(t)= \sqrt{\frac{2E}{T}}cos(2\pi f_{c} t + \dfrac{2\pi}{M}i),$} &  i=0, 1, ..., M-1\\
    & $ 0 \leq t \leq T$ 
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
```

[image: desired output]

This is my current code:

```
\begin{align}\label{M-ary PSK}
S(t)= \sqrt{\frac{2E}{T}}cos(2\pi f_{c} t + \dfrac{2\pi}{M}i),&\quad 
i=0, 1, ..., M-1\\
& \quad 0 \leq t \leq T \nonumber
\end{align}
```

[image: current output]

Any help or tips is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{M-ary PSK}
S(t)= \sqrt{\frac{2E}{T}}\cos(2\pi f_{c} t + \frac{2\pi}{M}i),\qquad
    \begin{aligned}
&i=0, 1, \dots, M-1\\
&0 \leq t \leq T
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

changes (in comparison t your code snipped):

- `\cos` instead `cos` (*cos* meaning three variable: *c*, *o* and *s*)
- conditions follows main equation in `aligned` environment from package `amsmath`
- instead of `...` is used `\dots`

**edit:**
or as pointed [Ari Brodsky](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21053/ari-brodsky) in comment below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{M-ary PSK}
S(t)= \sqrt{\frac{2E}{T}}\cos(2\pi f_{c} t + \frac{2\pi}{M}i),\qquad
    \begin{gathered}  % <-- changed
i=0, 1, \dots, M-1\\
0 \leq t \leq T
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `gathered` environment (rather than `aligned`) would more closely match the intended output, and is more sensible here, given that there is no natural alignment point in the subformulas.

Comment: Why `mathtools`?

Comment: @AriBrodsky, ups, now work also with `amsmath` :). in the my first test i receive error (not defined) .... so i changed to `mathtools`. i don't know what happen at that time :(. corrected

Comment: @AmirEmami, then you can vote for both of answer and accept this one, which on the best way solve your problem ((by clicking on up-pen and check marks, which are on the top left side of each answer). happy tex-ing!

Comment: Sure thing.

Hey Zarko, Would you mind me asking what your academic background is?

Comment: here on site i like for some reason preserve mine privacy :). i can only say, that i'm quit familiar with your equation ...

Answer (score 5):

You can just set the dual conditions using an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  S(t) = \sqrt{ \tfrac{2E}{T} } \cos \bigl( 2\pi f_c t + \tfrac{2\pi}{M} i \bigr), \quad 
  \begin{array}{c}
    i = 0, 1, \dots, M-1 \\[\jot]
    0 \leq t \leq T
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Consider using `\dots` rather than `...`.